# Two Different Button on same place

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am creating a chat app.
I have a send button where when I click on the button, messages are sent.
What I want to do is when the input text field is blank the send button must change to audio record button, and once the user starts typing, the audio record button must turn to send button. I am trying `if else` function here setting two different, but I am facing problems.

```
lazy var inputContainerView:UIView = {
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#e0e0e0")

    let uploadImageView = UIImageView()
    uploadImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    uploadImageView.image = UIImage(named: "attachment")
    uploadImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    uploadImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(attachmentButton)))
    containerView.addSubview(uploadImageView)
    // Constraints x,y,width,height
    uploadImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    uploadImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    uploadImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    uploadImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    let recordAudioButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let sendbutton = UIButton(type: .system)

    containerView.addSubview(inputTextFiled)
    containerView.addSubview(sendbutton)
    containerView.addSubview(recordAudioButton)
    if inputTextFiled.text == nil {
    sendbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "sendf"), for: .normal)
    sendbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    containerView.addSubview(sendbutton)

    // Constraints x,y,width,height
    sendbutton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    sendbutton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    sendbutton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    sendbutton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        inputTextFiled.isEnabled = true
        sendbutton.isHidden = true
        sendbutton.isEnabled = false
        recordAudioButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_voice"), for: .normal)
        recordAudioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        recordAudioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordAudioButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        inputTextFiled.addSubview(recordAudioButton)
        //Constraints x,y,width,height
        recordAudioButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        recordAudioButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        recordAudioButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        recordAudioButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    }
    containerView.addSubview(inputTextFiled)

    //Constraints x,y,width,height

    inputTextFiled.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadImageView.rightAnchor, constant:8).isActive = true
    inputTextFiled.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTextFiled.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendbutton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTextFiled.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor,constant: -15).isActive = true

    inputTextFiled.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    inputTextFiled.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let seperatorLineView = UIView()
    seperatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    seperatorLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(seperatorLineView)

    //Constraints X,Y,Width,Height
    seperatorLineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    seperatorLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    seperatorLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    seperatorLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.5).isActive = true

     return containerView
}()
```

Here the problem is when the audio record button shows that input text field does not show up only the containerView shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After a lot a trial and error I finally found the way to achive, But if anyone finds any other method do post

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let startinglength = textField.text?.count ?? 0
    let lengthToAdd = string.count
    let lengthToReplace = range.length
    let newLength = startinglength + lengthToAdd - lengthToReplace
    if newLength == 0 {
        print("textFiled Empty")
        self.recordAudioButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_voice"), for: .normal)
       self.recordAudioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.recordAudioButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
       self.recordAudioButton.isEnabled = true
        self.recordAudioButton.isHidden = false
        self.sendbutton.isEnabled = false
        self.sendbutton.isHidden = true
    } else {
        print("textfiled")
        UIView.transition(with: sendbutton, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.sendbutton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "sendf"), for: .normal)
            self.sendbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sendButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.recordAudioButton.isEnabled = false
            self.recordAudioButton.isHidden = true
            self.sendbutton.isEnabled = true
            self.sendbutton.isHidden = false
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two buttons. All you need to do is changing the image of the button based on the textField status using **button.setImage(image: UIImage?, for: UIControlState)**. If the textField.isEmpty, set the image to audio, else set it to send. Inside the button @IBAction, you can have if else statement to check which action to perform according to the state of the button.

Comment: I tried this method but it was not updating in real time and the button used to perform both the action

Comment: does your VC conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`? You should update the image and status of your button inside the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` . Don't forget to return true

Comment: Yeah I did the same i posted the answer here too Thanks tho